# How to access children's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, parent-child, react-native-router-flux

If I have the following structure using RNRF:

```
<Scene tabs={true} tabBarComponent={()=><ScrollableTabBar items={["Approval", "My Request", " DO Customer", "My Confirm", "View Request"]}/>} tabBarPosition='top' lazy={true}>
       <Scene key="Home" hideNavBar component={Home} title={"Home"} name='Home'/>
</Scene>
```

How would I access `name` props of the child scene from within my `ScrollableTabBar` which is just a component passed to the parent scene?

I thought the children of parent `<Scene>` would be passed along to the component `<ScrollableTabBar>`, but when I tried `this.props.children` from `ScrollableTabBar` it's returning undefined.

Thanks in advance for any pointers! :)

Answer (score 1):

My reputation is below 50 hence I couldn't post a comment.

Any reason you need to have a `name` prop as `Scene` has already provided both `key` and `title` which should be sufficient

Comment: I just want to access `name` from within `ScrollableTabBar` because it says in the documentation key and title (and any other props already in use by `<Scene>`) won't be passed along to whatever listed as `component`, hence I'm creating arbitrary props so it would be passed to the component. I don't know if I understood this sentence "Any other props not listed here will be pass on to the specified Scene's component" from the `Scene` [docs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#scene) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Any attribute with value passed to component act as props. So if you want to pass name too with items you can add one more attribute to `ScrollableTabBar` like :

```
<ScrollableTabBar items={["Approval", "My Request", " DO Customer", "My Confirm", "View Request"]} name={passValueofName}/>
```

You can access name like **`this.props.name`** just like you access `this.props.items` inside `ScrollableTabBar`

Comment: does that mean if I do: `<ScrollableTabBar items={["Approval", "My Request", " DO Customer", "My Confirm", "View Request"]} children={this.props.children}/>` it will allow me to access parent scene's children? In this case Scene with Home component?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter by accident, I have editted the comment

Comment: Yes, if there `this.props.children` exists & have valid value at time of invoking `ScrollableTabBar ` you will have `this.props.children` available inside ScrollableTabBar component

Comment: if you are using any store like mobx or redux for values, same reference is passed & UI elements is updated with any change too

Comment: looking at my structure, I don't think `this.props.children` would exist though. what I want to access from `ScrollableTabBar` is pretty much the `Scene` containing `Home` component. Do u have any suggestion on how i can achieve that?

Comment: Easiest is to pass `this.props.children` into whole hierarchy from parent element where it exists OR use `store` like mobx or redux orthunk that will have value for components at anytime that can be passed as reference with respect to store object